# removing git reference from nest application

Tags: javascript, typescript, github, nestjs, nestjs-config

how do I remove the Git reference that comes with the nest app created with the nest new command using npm. as I have not been able to commit Github.

I tried git add . I saw an unexpected error: 'server/' does not have a commit checked out
fatal: adding files failed. server being the name of the nest application.

Comment: Can you show your project directory structure?

Comment: Are you in the actual directory with the git project? Are you in an existing project and adding a nest project via `nest new`? If so is this a monorepo? There's a lot of missing context here